# Algorithm for calender recurrence in android

Tags: android, algorithm, calendar, recurrence

Am looking for algorithm to implement calendar recurrence in my android application.
frequency of recurrence is daily, weekly, monthly, yearly. I need occurrence dates, number of occurrences before end date of appointment. 
  Algorithm can be RFC 2445 or any.

So, can anyone please help me.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't here to do your work for you. Try something first and ask specific questions when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this library:

http://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/